# Concatenate comments from same author : Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to achieve the following task
"Comments from the same user on the same property will be concatenated to form one large comment for a user on a particular property"

Any ideas please...

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Do you mean that if a user comments 4 times on a blog post, you'd like all 4 of those comments joined together into 1 long comment?  If that's the case, how are you going to preserve the flow of a discussion in the comments?